# Переход с MySQL на MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники сообщества ХэшКод. Я как человек, который только начал осваивать основы PHP, застрял на одном вопросе.

В общем, есть код, мне нужно переписать его с MySQL на MySQLi. Но мне немного непонятно, как. Если можете, растолкуйте, покажите пример. Посещал сайты, которые рекомендовал поисковик, но так и не нашел нужного мне ответа. За любую помощь буду искренне благодарен.

```
if (isset($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
   # Проверяем существование аккаунта с данными пользователя.
   if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". $db->real_escape_string($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". md5($db->real_escape_string($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"), 0) == 1)
    {
       # Создаем массив с данными пользователя.
       $account = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". $db->real_escape_string($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". md5($db->real_escape_string($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"));

      # Создаем ID в сессии.
       $_SESSION['account_id'] = $account['id'];

        # Записываем дату последнего посещения.
       mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `date_last_entry` = '". time() ."' WHERE `id` = '". $account['id'] ."' LIMIT 1");
    }
    else $err .= 'Система Вас не распознала. Авторизоваться не удалось.<br />';}
```

**Обновление**

Смотрел, ничего все равно не могу понять. 
Какими именно функциями нужно это заменять:

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". input($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". encrypt(input($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"), 0) == 1)
    {
        # Массив с данными пользователя
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". input($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". encrypt(input($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"));
```

`num_rows` или что-то подобное. Мне бы пример, а дальше, я думаю, разберусь.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? Посмотрите в документации, чем каждая mysqli_* функция отличается от своего аналога в mysql_* и внесите необходимые изменения.

Comment: Смотрел, ничего все равно не могу понять. 
Какими именно функциями нужно это заменять:
`if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". input($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". encrypt(input($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"), 0) == 1)
    {
        # Массив с данными пользователя
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '". input($_GET['login']) ."' AND `password` = '". encrypt(input($_GET['password'])) ."' LIMIT 1"));`
num_rows или что-то подобное. Мне бы пример, а дальше я думаю разберусь.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить "по-простому", то вам необходимо в функциях mysql_query, mysql_result, mysql_fetch_assoc, mysql_connect и т.д. добавить букву "i" после слова mysql. Тогда вы как бы перейдете с mysql на процедурный вид mysqli. :)

Comment: Ну про это я читал, так же пробовал и этот метод. Но бывает вылетают предупреждения, что некоторых функций не существует. Мне, проще говоря, легче этот способ использовать: `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');`

Мне бы просто пример. :)

Comment: @VaDoSiQ, мне лень гуглить (это должны делать вы), но если я не ошибаюсь, то mysqli_query первым параметром принимает дескриптор подключения, а mysql_result нужно заменить на mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае рекомендую этот класс для работы с mysqli

[SafeMysql](http://www.phpfaq.ru/SafeMysql) | [Статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165069/)